# css bottom border not working properly?

Tags: css

This is my html file which stores some customer details

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Home.css" />
        <title>Customer</title>
    </head>
      <body>
            <form id="formId" jwcid="formId@Form" success="ognl:listeners.addCustomer">

                <table>
                         <h3 id="customerTab1">Customer Data</h3>
                         <!--TextField for taking customerId-->

                         <!--TextField for taking customerName-->
                         <tr>
                             <td><label id="customerlabel1">Customer Name:</label>
                             <input type="text" jwcid="@TextField" id="customername" value="ognl:customerName"/></td>
                         </tr>
                         <!--TextField for taking customerAddress-->
                         <tr>
                             <td><label id="customerlabel2">Customer Address:</label>
                                 <textarea rows="2" cols="20" jwcid="@TextArea" id="address" value="ognl:address"></textarea>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                    </table> 
                        <h3 id="customerTab2" >Select Gender</h3>
                        <!--RadioGroup with Radio buttons to select Gender--> 

                            <span id="customerGender" jwcid="customerGender@RadioGroup" selected="ognl:customerGender">
                                <Input type="radio" name="customerGender" jwcid="@Radio" value="0"/><label id="customermale">Male</label>
                                <Input type="radio" name="customerGender" jwcid="@Radio" value="1" /><label id="customerfemale">Female</label>
                            </span>


                        <h3 id="customerTab3" >Select Service</h3>
                          <!--Checkbox to select Service--> 
                         <Input type="checkbox" id="customerPrivilege" jwcid="customerPrivilege@Checkbox" value="1" selected="ognl:customerPrivilege"/>
                         <label id="privilegecustomer">Privileged Customer</label>
                        <!--List to select PaymnetMode--> 
                        <h3 id="customerTab4">Customer List</h3>


                             <select>
                                 <span jwcid="@For" source='ognl:customerList' value='ognl:currentCustomerData' keyExpression="id">
                                     <option jwcid="@Any" value='ognl:currentCustomerData.id'><span jwcid="@Insert" value='ognl:currentCustomerData.customerName'></span></option>
                                 </span>
                             </select>
                            <!--Buttons to perform desired action-->
                             <input id="submitform" type="Submit" value="Add Customer" />

            </form>      

        </body>
</html>

 2. CSS code


html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
body
{
    margin: 17% 25%;

    border-width: 1em; 

    border-style: groove;
    border-color: orange;

    background-image:url('blue.BMP');

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50%;

    background-size:100%;

}
textarea {
    position: absolute;
    left: 48.2%;
    height: 5%;

    resize: none;
    width:12%;
    top: 34%;
}
#customerlabel1
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 34%;
    top: 30%;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#customerlabel2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 34%;
    top: 34%;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#customername {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 48%;
    top: 29.5%;
}
#customerGender
{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 42%;
    top: 47%;
}
#customermale
{

    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;

}
#customerfemale
{

    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;

}
#customerPrivilege
{
    position: absolute; 
    left:40%;
    top: 57%;

}
#privilegecustomer
{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 42%;
    top: 57%;
     font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#customerTab1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 26%;
    background-color:fuchsia ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#customerTab2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top: 42%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    background-repeat:  repeat-x;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#customerTab3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42%;
    top:  52%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    background-repeat:  repeat-x;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#customerTab4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 62%;
    left: 42%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
    background-repeat:  repeat-x;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;


}
select {
    position: absolute;
    left: 44%;
    top: 66%;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#submitform
{
    position: absolute ;
    left: 44%;
    top: 70%;

}
```

Comment: somebody pls answer this..its working in every browser except firefox and IE 8

Comment: http://sscce.org/ should be provided

Comment: You are not setting border bottom separately at all, just border in all directions. You are not specifying which border should appear and how. The code is neither a working page nor a minimal document constructed to demonstrate a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from your question, but I'm guessing your problem is that the border is not properly wrapping the `body` of your html. This is happening because you are absolutely positioning all the elements inside your `form` inside the `body`. Since all the elements are absolutely positioned, no elements are actually inside the body's layout, so the browser is giving the body a height of 0.

I would recommend rewriting your css to avoid most of the absolute positioning of the form elements.

Comment: what if i position body absolute?

Comment: @surajR That wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear (what elements border is in question - and only the css classes that apply to that element?), but in general, some browsers won't display a border if the object is empty (has no displayable content).

To get around this, put a "space" in empty objects, for example:

```
<td>
</td>
```

will become

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Comment: but there are no empty objects..read code carefully...try on your machine..it work well an all browsers but not in firefox and IE

Comment: @surajR if you have IE9 installed you can press F12, look at the CSS applying to that specific object (by clicking that object) it will show all inherited CSS codes, you can also untick values to see how it changes

Comment: i am working on windows xp which dont support iE9..so pls tell me some reliable alternative